# Is It Possible to Have a Textbox with Facebook Registration Plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, registration

We are going to use the facebook registration plugin but we want to have a large text box as one of the fields? Is this possible? I can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

> `type`: The field type. Supported values are text, date, select, checkbox, typeahead, and hidden.